# Unable to receive money from MoneyGram

Tags: india, money-transfer, australia

I'm an Indian  citizen and last time my Australian friend had sent me some cash through money gram.  But I was unable to withdraw. MoneyGram said that the person sending money should also be an Indian.

Is there another way so I can get money without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> MoneyGram said that the person sending money should also be an Indian.

There shouldn't be any such restriction. Can you check again what exactly the issue was?

> Is there another way so I can get money without any problem.

You can try Bank Transfers or alternative remittance like Western Union

Comment: No they can't  give us money if the sender is not an Indian.